# Opening router ports by UPnP in Ruby

Tags: ruby, upnp

I know it should be possible to communicate with a NAT/Router on a local network and ask for ports to be forwarded via UPnP, but I don't know any of the specifics.

I've found [a gem](http://rubyforge.org/frs/shownotes.php?group_id=1513&release_id=35786) that looks like it might be useful, but beyond that I'm at a loss (The gem's homepage appears to be down).

Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Seattle.rb project. Somehow they have re-organized their homepage. The correct link is now [http://SeattleRb.**RubyForge.**Org/UPnP/](http://SeattleRb.RubyForge.Org/UPnP/) instead of just http://SeattleRb.Org/UPnP/

You can find all the UPnP projects [on the Seattle.rb homepage](http://SeattleRb.Org/) or on the [Seattle.rb RubyForge page](http://SeattleRb.RubyForge.Org/), near the bottom of the page, with links to their RDocs.

Comment: Thats really helpful, thanks! Looks like a bit of a slog while I wade through the UPnP IGD details, but I appreciate the tip!

Comment: unfortunately it looks like the UPnP-IGD gem they provide can't write to IGDs, only read! Looks like I'm going to be rolling my own…

Comment: Hey @JP did you roll your own? I'm looking for a UPnP lib for ruby.

Comment: Sadly I never did - I haven't even looked at this area of Ruby for a few years, and unlikely to have any time to do so soon. Sorry I can't be of more help!